# how to write routerLink test case using jasmine-karma in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, angular-test

I just want to test whether the `routeLink='/home'` is available in App.Component.html page or not. Somewhere in Udemy I saw a video on how to test routerLink. I followed the same step but I don't know if this is a problem with Visual Studio Code or somewhere else in angular testing.

*NOTE: Please must read the comment in code*

The test is as follow,

```
it('AppPage should have a router link named home', async(() => {

    let debugElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkWithHref))

     /* 
       Here visual studio code doesn't give me intellisense for findIndex method.
       when I write 'x.', it doesn't give me intellisense for properties 
       but I checked in DOM that such properties property exists. What's wrong? 
     */

    let index = debugElements.findIndex(x=>x.properties['href']==='/home');


    expect(index).toBeGreaterThan(-1);
}))
```

`properties` property exists as shown here,

[image]

But actually I get error like this,

[image]

What's the problem?